# timediff is greater than 2 minutes

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query where I can eliminate a timediff of less than 2 minutes. I have tried variations on the following which returns no results

```
 timediff(sessions.producer_on,sessions.producer_off)>'00:02:00'
```

the timediff without the > works fine and returns all results  - I am having difficulty with the >00:02:00 condition. Can anyone help - many thanks

Comment: Please consider selecting the "best answer" if Vincent provided a solution for you.

Answer (score 10):

You need to extract the minute from the time then compare it.

```
minute(timediff(sessions.producer_on,sessions.producer_off)) > 2 AND 
hour(timediff(sessions.producer_on,sessions.producer_off)) = 0
```

Also it may be necessary to make sure that the hour is 0 since only when the hour is zero does the minute actually matter.

Answer (score 10):

This is probably the "old way" but it eliminates the need to check hours, days, etc.

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fieldOne) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fieldTwo) < 120
```

You can also use `NOW()` in place of a field name.

Answer (score 10):

Change it to

```
timediff(sessions.producer_on,sessions.producer_off) > TIME('00:02:00')
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM e_email_otp WHERE TIMEDIFF('2019-01-11 10-46-19',`2019-01-11 10-45-19`) <'00:02:00.000000'
```

Comment: question mentioned 2 minutes, not 5 !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what helped me in similar case:

> TIMESTAMPDIFF(second ,sessions.producer_on,sessions.producer_off) < 60